# At what daily dose does daily aspirin use become dangerous for a long-term user?

Tags: medications, toxicity, dosage, nsaids-pain-meds

Many people take 80-300mg a day of aspirin for cardiovascular reasons; while, from what I've seen online, arthritis patients take up to 3000mg a day (is this correct?). But what are the increased risks associated with such a high daily intake? At what daily dose does aspirin become dangerous?

I've found many accounts of acute poisoning, but no quantitative studies on the chronic effects over time, as a function of dosage -- it's surprisingly hard to find information on this (I've tried every keyword combination under the sun).

Comment: Sorry I can’t answer your question, but I am wondering the exact same thing. I have extensive arthritis and have found hot (Bikram) Yoga to be extremely beneficial. Sometimes, though, I’ll overdo it and aspirin helps with the resulting pain. I’d like to take a couple of full strength aspirin every night, but maybe I should take something else that won’t cause bleeding. I hope someone does have a real answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Aspirin, just like all NDSAIDs, affects enzymes associated with pain transmission; they are COX-1 and COX-2 (cyclooxygenase-1 and 2). COX-1 helps protect the stomach and intestinal lining from the acids the stomach produces [<sup>1</sup>](https://www.rxlist.com/cox-2_inhibitors/drugs-condition.htm). Since NSAIDs inhibit the production of these enzymes, they also leave your stomach and intestinal lining somewhat unprotected from acids. This is what can cause damage from long-term use of NSAIDs. It's not so much that they burn a hole in your stomach, but that they reduce the protection offered by the COX-1 enzyme. Of course, the higher the dose, the greater the effect on these enzymes, and the longer NSAIDs are taken, the greater the gastrointestinal risk. Except for low-dose aspirin, NSAIDs should not be taken longer than necessary.
__________
1. https://www.rxlist.com/cox-2_inhibitors/drugs-condition.htm

Comment: Lacks citations.

Comment: Did you see my footnote (superscript)?

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, no, I didn't. Too tiny. Probably not the best way to add links but I'm reversing my downvote. (I had to make a trivial edit of adding a space to allow me to reverse it.)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I use a footnote style link where a regular hyperlink just doesn't fit. I don't use it often.

Answer (score 3):

Aspirin is a platelet inhibitor.  As such it has a [number of bleeding risks](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/heart-disease/in-depth/daily-aspirin-therapy/art-20046797?pg=2) - including GI bleeding as described above. Risks also include increased bleeding risk from injury including cuts, bruising, or hitting your head and having a brain bleed. And actually, even without head trauma, an **intracranial hemorrhage risk increases with the dose of aspirin.** The same dose of aspirin is not safe for everyone.

This does NOT mean that aspirin is too risky to [take for primary or secondary prevention of heart disease, ischemic stroke, etc](https://www.health.harvard.edu/heart-health/weighing-the-risks-and-benefits-of-aspirin-therapy) - it means you need to have a discussion with your doctor on the [risks and benefits of whether daily (or even as-needed) aspirin is **right for your personal situation**](http://stroke.ahajournals.org/content/36/8/1801) and if so, what dose.  And you/your doctor need to know what other medications you take daily and what others you might take when you need it - because some interact with aspirin.  Again you need a doctor to advise you on what daily dose is right for you.

Arthritis pain has many possible treatments. Your doctor can help develop a specialized treatment plan.

Answer (score 2):

Commonly prescribed dose of aspirin for certain types of arthritis can be as high as 4 g/day ([Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/dosage/aspirin.html)).

For angina pectoris and heart attack prevention, even low doses (75-325 mg/day) can result in gastrointestinal bleeding ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17257477)).

According to one study ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10643705)):

> Mini-dose aspirin...(75 mg/day), caused significant changes in renal
>   function and uric acid handling within 1 week in a group of elderly
>   inpatients...

Surely, side effects depend on the dose and treatment duration but also on an individual's susceptibility. So, I think it would be irresponsible to mention any specific aspirin dose as "safe dose".

The recommendations about "Safe Daily Use of Aspirin" by the US Food and Drug Administration [FDA.gov](https://www.fda.gov/Drugs/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/BuyingUsingMedicineSafely/UnderstandingOver-the-CounterMedicines/SafeDailyUseofAspirin/ucm291434.htm) do not mention any aspirin dose at all.